# When a bug is fixed and the report closed on github, can I immediately update my library to include the fix?

Tags: github

Pretty basic question in the title.

I'm just wondering because I noticed a bunch of warnings when I was using Pandas.DataFrame.hist() in my notebook. I googled the warnings and saw that there was a bug report on github that was reported as fixed 6 days ago. I tried to use pip to upgrade Pandas, but the warnings are still there. Is this user error on my part, or do developers wait til they fix a lot of bugs and then release the fixes all at once?

Thanks for entertaining a noob question.

Comment: Probably not. You would need to wait until the commit that fixes the bug is merged into a release and then that release version is registered to the PyPi repository. Alternatively you could pull the fixed version of the source code from GitHub and build it from scratch which may or may not be straightforward.

Comment: @jodag Thanks. If you are into internet street cred, I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer. Either way, good info!